# How to cross-compile OpenVPN to an old kernel

Tags: openvpn, compile

I'm trying to build the VPN client for my NAS which is an ARMv5 CPU with Linux 2.6:

```
Linux OSS117 2.6.22.18 #15 Wed May 25 15:23:11 CST 2011 armv5tejl GNU/Linux
```

The compilation machine is a Debian 9 x86_64:

```
Linux dikkenek 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1 (2016-09-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have basically followed [these steps](https://gist.github.com/Anubisss/afea82b97058e418e8030ee35e40f54f) (compile instructions for openssl, libzo and openvpn) which work perfectly well, but the program refuses to run on the target host because the kernel is too old:

```
bicou@OSS117:~$ ./openvpn 
FATAL: kernel too old
Aborted
```

I have then, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11207190/334493), retrieved glibc and compiled it with `--enable-kernel=2.6.22` which worked like a charm.

I have then modified the OpenVPN makefile using [these instructions](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Tips_and_Tricks/How_to_Build_an_application_with_your_own_custom_glibc) (I have adapted to use the cross-compiler GCC instead of the system one when searching for file paths, and it works because it points to `/usr/lib/gcc-cross` instead of the default `/usr/lib/gcc`) but now the compilation fails with this:

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: /home/bicou/dns-325-cross/bin/lib/libcrypto.a(v3_utl.o): undefined reference to symbol '__isoc99_sscanf@@GLIBC_2.7'
//usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:562: recipe for target 'openvpn' failed
make: *** [openvpn] Error 1
```

So I figured I had to recompile zo and openssl with the dedicated glibc but that doesn't work either (compilation worked though).

I feel I am very close to attaining what I want, but I'm stuck at the link-with-glibc step.

Here are the versions I used:

- glibc-2.25
- lzo-2.09
- openssl-1.0.2j
- openvpn-2.3.12

Comment: I ended up installing a compiler on the target system. That's not exactly what I wanted even if the initial goal was to have OpenVPN running on the NAS. I'm still curious as to how to compile that from the x86 machine.